# git-bash problem while trying to clone a project

Tags: git, github, git-bash

i am trying to clone a project from git bash, but receive an error.  Following is the command I am running and the response of git bash. Please let me know what could be the problem.

```
$ git clone git@path:application_name.git

Cloning into application_name...

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Permission denied (publickey) is an SSH error. Do you have access to the remote machine with SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged it with Github, have you added the public part of your SSH key to their system so that they know who you are and that you are allowed to push/pull from that repository.

This will help get you started: http://help.github.com/set-up-git-redirect/